# TDataSetProvider and Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2009, database-deadlocks

Could you list what are the conditions for Dead Locks in the TDataSetProviders?

We got complicated code, and a deadlock accurse mostly on a loop over the table.

What is worse, i could not reproduce the deadlock while debugged in the IDE, only on lunch.

Could you hint where to look?

Comment: The reason why you couldn't reproduce it could be that a deadlock will normally not occur for a single client. Your "loop over the table" sounds like a long client transaction updating/locking multiple records (possibly the whole table) which increases the chance of a deadlock when other clients try to update. Try running a single SQL statement in a transaction (no loop on the client) and commit/rollback as soon as possible.

Comment: i run the test from two diffrent computers. ill try transaction. thanks.